# OMNET++ How to retain all functions in AODVRouting class but override sendAODVPacket function only?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm writting a simple module to simulate a misbehaved node that inherits all functions from AODRouting, and overriding sendAODVPacket function by dropping the AODV packet once it has received it. The .h file as follows:

```
#ifndef __PROJECT1_SELFISHBASENODE_H_
#define __PROJECT1_SELFISHBASENODE_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "AODVRouting.h"

using namespace inet;

class SelfishBaseNode : public AODVRouting
{

protected:
virtual void initialize();
virtual void sendAODVPacket(AODVControlPacket *packet, const L3Address&     destAddr, unsigned int timeToLive, double delay) override;

};

#endif
```

The CC file as follows:

```
#include "SelfishBaseNode.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

Define_Module(SelfishBaseNode);

void SelfishBaseNode::initialize()
{
}


void SelfishBaseNode::sendAODVPacket(AODVControlPacket *packet, const L3Address& destAddr, unsigned int timeToLive, double delay)
{
    EV << "Received message, dropping message now\n";
    delete packet;
}
```

.NED file as follows:

```
package project1;


import inet.node.aodv.AODVRouter;

module snode extends AODVRouter
{
    parameters:
    //@networkNode;
    @display("i=device/wifilaptop");
    @labels(wireless-node);
    @class(SelfishBaseNode);

       submodules:
        bad: SelfishBaseNode {
        @display("p=273,350");
    }
}
```

When I rebuild my project, i got these error:

```
SelfishBaseNode.h:35:18: error: 'sendAODVPacket' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `sendAODVPacket()` is declared in `AODVRouting.h` without `virtual`. You should add `virtual` before declaration of `sendAODVPacket()` in `AODVRouting` class in `AODVRouting.h`