# OMNET++ Transmit message via Ethernet or Wireless

Tags: c++, omnet++

i am new in using the OMNET++ simulator. Currently i want to build a network which consists of two or more nodes, each having two interfaces on which they can send messages out (e.g. Ethernet and Wireless).

I want to program the node behavior by myself. When a message arrives at a host, i want to define in the `handleMessage(cMessage *msg)` method, whether the host should transmit the received message via Ethernet or Wireless interface.

Can i take the WirelessHost from the INET package for this scenario? If yes, how can i program the decision on what interface to use for retransmitting the received message? I followed the wireless tutorial from INET, but they only configure `.ned` and `.ini` files but not the `.cc` files where the behavior is coded.

In the tutorial the `UdpBasicApp` was used. It would be nice if i could write an own App like described above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Right. You can tune your own node, just creating a new one (.h .ned .cc file), that can import and reuse Wireless host features and add/override extra functions. 
So a custom MyNode.cc file for new MyNode element could be:

```
#include "MyNode.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

void MyNode::initialize()
{
}

void MyNode::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
 EV << "Received message, now applying new custom procedure \n";
 new_behaviour msg;
}
```

Also can help you here a complete sample of a new node created to delete all received packets [OMNET++ How to retain all functions in AODVRouting class but override sendAODVPacket function only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204764/omnet-how-to-retain-all-functions-in-aodvrouting-class-but-override-sendaodvpa)

Cheers!